# Integrating Keycloak with React using OIDC-Client and encountering a 404 error upon login page. What am I missing in the server portal configuration?

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, oidc-client, keycloak-nodejs-connect

oidc-client 404 page not found

i was try to integrate keycloack react using oidc-client library , the code below is my configuration with oidc-client

```
const settings = {
  authority: "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master",
  client_id: "reactAppAone",
  redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/ondemand",
  response_type: 'code',
  scope: "openid profile message.read",
};

const userManager = new UserManager(settings);
```

my login page code

```
 useEffect(() => {
      userManager.login();
    }, [])
```

when i try runing it in login page i'm getting the following error

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ oidc-client.min.js:1
t @ oidc-client.min.js:1
t @ oidc-client.min.js:1
t @ oidc-client.min.js:1
t @ oidc-client.min.js:1
t @ oidc-client.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ oidc-client.min.js:49
Promise.then (async)
t @ oidc-client.min.js:49
t @ oidc-client.min.js:49
login @ auth_helper.js:18
(anonymous) @ login.js:15
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:24926
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24891
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24878
commitPassiveMountEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24866
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27039
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26769
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
```

can any one help me out with this im missing any configuration in server portal ?